# ngnix rewrite rule is not working as expected

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have one micro python flask service running locally.
one of urls is http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/app/3/user/

I want this service to run through ngnix like below:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/service1/v1/app/3/user/

I have done following changes in nginx.conf.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
}  

location /service1 {
        rewrite ^/service1/(.*)$ /$1 last;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

but I am getting it as below on my local server as /service1/v1/app/3/user/ instead of /v1/app/3/user/

As I am new to nginx, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you should use break instead of last

Comment: It worked. thanks .but can you please explain more about it. it would be great

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite